# Map and transform methods with using serializable class on DStream elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, data-mining, bigdata

I am writing app that will be extract logs, so I implemented function (Lisitng 1) which is taking string as parametr and extracts valuable informations (regexs: Listing  2) from it. I wanted that this method could be send to other workers so I impelemnt serializable class.

I have problem with apply this method on DStreams. Here is my streams minning solution:

```
def streamMinner(): Unit = {

   val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
   val logsStream = ssc.textFileStream("logs/")

// Not works 
   val extractLogs = logsStream.map( log => new Matcher().matchLog(log))
   extractLogs.print(1)

// Works
// val words = logsStream.transform( rdd => rdd.map( log => matchLog(log)))
// words.print()

   ssc.start()
   ssc.awaitTermination()

  }
```

Problem is in line where every element of logsStream is maped with new object of Matcher class (new Matcher().matchLog(log)
Apache Spark gave my below errors:

```
ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on host1: Container marked as failed: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_01_000003 on host: host1. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_01_000003
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 5 on host2: Container marked as failed: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_01_000006 on host: host2. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_01_000006
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50
```

...

```
ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 6  ...

ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
17/07/11 09:41:09 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1499758850000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, host1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 6 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_01_000007 on host: host1. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_01_000007
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1433)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1421)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1642)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:622)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1856)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1882)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1335)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1309)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$5$1.apply(DStream.scala:768)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$5$1.apply(DStream.scala:767)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:227)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, host1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 6 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_01_000007 on host: host1. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_01_000007
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1433)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1421)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:801)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1642)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:622)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1856)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1882)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1335)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1309)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$5$1.apply(DStream.scala:768)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$5$1.apply(DStream.scala:767)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:227)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


scala> 17/07/11 09:41:11 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from host3/11.11.11.11:11111 is closed
17/07/11 09:41:11 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 4 on host3: Slave lost
17/07/11 09:41:12 ERROR TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 7741519719369750843 to host3/11.11.11.11:11111: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
17/07/11 09:41:12 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on host2: Slave lost
17/07/11 09:41:12 ERROR TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 7734757459881277232 to host3//11.11.11.11:11111: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
17/07/11 09:41:12 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 3 on host4: Slave lost
17/07/11 09:41:12 ERROR TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 5816053641531447955 to host3//11.11.11.11:11111: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
17/07/11 09:41:12 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 7 on host2: Slave lost
17/07/11 09:41:13 ERROR TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 8774007142277591342 to host3/11.11.11.11:11111: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
17/07/11 09:41:13 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 8 on host1: Slave lost
17/07/11 09:41:19 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on host3: Container marked as failed: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_02_000002 on host: host3. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e743_1499728610705_0043_02_000002
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50
```

When I comment lines:

```
val extractLogs = logsStream.map( log => new Matcher().matchLog(log))
   extractLogs.print(1)
```

and I uncomment lines:

```
// val words = logsStream.transform( rdd => rdd.map( log => matchLog(log)))
// words.print()
```

Everything works fine. My question is why? I'm afraid that solution that works may not be parallelized on cluster because method matchLog is not serializable. Someone has a similar problem or know how to deal with it?

Lisitng 1:

```
case class logValues2(time_stamp: String, action: String, protocol: String, connection_id: String, src_ip: String, dst_ip: String, src_port: String, dst_port: String, duration: String, bytes: String, user: String) extends Serializable

class Matcher extends Serializable {
    def matchLog(x: String): logValues2 = {
      var dst_ip = " "
      var dst_port = " "

      var time_stamp = time_stamp_reg.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
      var action = action_reg.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
      var protocol = protocol_reg.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
      var connection_id = connection_id_reg.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
      var ips = ips_reg.findAllIn(x).mkString(" ").split(""" """)
      var src_ip = ips(0)
      if (ips.length > 1) {
        dst_ip = ips(1)
      } else {
        dst_ip = " "
      }

      var ports = ports_reg.findAllIn(x).mkString(" ").split(""" """)
      var src_port = ports(0)
      if (ports.length > 1) {
        dst_port = ports(1)
      } else {
        dst_port = " "
      }

      var duration = duration_reg.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
      var bytes = bytes_reg.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
      var user = user_reg.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")

      var logObject = logValues2(time_stamp, action, protocol, connection_id, src_ip, dst_ip, src_port, dst_port, duration, bytes, user)

      return logObject
    }
```

Above method is implemented also separately (no within Matcher class).

UPDATE:
My Regular expressions: Listing 2:

```
 val time_stamp_reg = """^.*?(?=\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s%)""".r
  val action_reg = """((?<=:\s)\w{4,10}(?=\s\w{2})|(?<=\w\s)(\w{7,9})(?=\s[f]))""".r
  val protocol_reg = """(?<=[\w:]\s)(\w+)(?=\s[cr])""".r
  val connection_id_reg = """(?<=\w\s)(\d+)(?=\sfor)""".r
  val ips_reg = """(?<=[\d\w][:\s])(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=\/\d+|\z| \w)""".r
  val ports_reg = """(?<=\d\/)(\d{1,6})(?=\z|[\s(])""".r
  val duration_reg = """(?<=duration\s)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(?=\s|\z)""".r
  val bytes_reg = """(?<=bytes\s)(\d+)(?=\s|\z)""".r
  val user_reg = """(?<=\\\\)(\d+)(?=\W)""".r
```

Comment: Your stacktrace is only describing the outer container failure, not the actual inner exception. What are these `*_reg` fields? Where are they defined? What types are they?

Comment: I updated my post adding regular expressions, do you need some other informations?

Comment: Where are they defined?

Comment: Before the definition of other methods or classes. These are global variables